# Compare files and delete some specific lines python

Tags: python, file, input

I have 2 files. Both of them have plenty of names line by line. First file has 184 lines and second one has 755 lines. I want to compare the lines from the first file with the lines from the second and the ones that are equal, i delete them from the first one. Thus, letting the first file only with the lines that are not equal or are not present in the second file. I've been trying here but there's some mistake i'm doing that i haven't spotted yet.

That's an example, both of files have this kind of names in this format, line by line:

```
Sociedade Ação
Águia de Marabá
Amazonas FC
América (RN)
Aparecidense
Araguacema
ASSU
Atibaia
Atlético Gloriense
...
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```py
with open('file1.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f1:
    names1 = f1.readlines()

with open('file2.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f2:
    names2 = f2.readlines()

with open('file1.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f3:
    for name in names1:
        if name in names2:
            continue
        f3.write(name)
```

> file1.txt

```
Sociedade Ação
Águia de Marabá
Amazonas FC
América (RN)
Aparecidense
Araguacema
ASSU
Atibaia
Atlético Gloriense
```

> file2.txt

```
Sociedade Ação
Águia de Marabá
Amazonas FC
dfgh
hdfgh
hdfgh
hdfghd
sdfs
sdfs
sdfs
sdfs
sdfs
sdfgsdfgsfgsd
sdfgsdfgsfgsd
sdfgsdfgsfgsd
sdfgsdfgsfgsd
```

> file1.txt after modification

```
América (RN)
Aparecidense
Araguacema
ASSU
Atibaia
Atlético Gloriense
```

Comment: The close() statements are unnecessary thanks to the `with` statement.

Comment: @user2891462 Thank-you, how did I miss that all this time. Today I learned something.

Comment: will `f3.write(name)` include line endings?  You could do: `print(name,file=f3)` instead.

Comment: @RufusVS yes, line endings are included as seen in the output I posted. Isn't that  the normal behaviour?

Comment: @Abhi_J I guess you are right, the line endings are included in the strings read in from the file.  I read my files in differently and also work with multiple programming languages which can behave differently, for instance writeln instead of write.